# Cosmological Constant Problem calculations involving energy densities

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, vacuum, cosmological-constant, fine-tuning

I am following [Timo Weigand lecutre notes on QFT, on page 28](https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/%7Emspannow/files/SkriptQFT_Weigand.pdf), he breifly touches on the Cosmological Constant Problem.

But I am a little confused.

He begins with a Lagrangian and include a nonzero $V_{0}$ in the classical theory, uses two finite terms $\epsilon_{0} , \chi$, that emerge in the quantum theory, and notes that $$\epsilon_{0}+V_{0}=\chi$$.

Then he notes that observationally we know that $\chi=(10^{-3}eV)^4$. That is we take $\chi$ as the cosmological constant in the field equations.

Here is what I do not understand:

**

> the net vacuum energy would be ***the difference*** of a finite piece
> $V_{0}$ and a finite quantum contribution $\epsilon_{0}$

**

But the equation above is a sum of two terms not the difference! Are we assuming that $V_{0}$  has  negative value?

I understand that if two finite positive terms on the scale of Plank, $(10^{19} GeV)^4$, are subtracted and give a many orders of magnitude smaller number $\chi=(10^{-3}eV)^4$, it is considered immense fine tuning.

But again the big terms are not subtracted but added up!

Shouldn't we take $V_{0}$ as the cosmological constant and say observationally we know that $V_{0}=(10^{-3}eV)^4$?

Looks like in this case it makes better sense because now $$V_{0}=\chi-\epsilon_{0}$$ that is the difference of two Plank scale finite terms, from the quantum theory, is equal to a much much smaller term, $V_{0}$ from the classical theory and cosmology, and that is fine tuning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author was merely uncareful with their wording. They meant that the net vacuum energy would be the sum of the classical and quantum contributions ($\epsilon_0+V_0$), or that it would be the difference of their magnitudes ($\Big||\epsilon_0|-|V_0|\Big|$). Note that:

> Are we assuming that $V_{0}$  has  negative value?

Since $\chi$ is measured to be small and both $\epsilon_0$ and $V_0$ are expected to be much larger in magnitude, either $\epsilon_0$ or $V_0$ must be negative in order to satisfy the equation $\chi=\epsilon_0+V_0$.

Comment: Must be negative, why? Where the inequality comes from?

Comment: @VVM added clarification.

Comment: appreciate your help and answer accepted.